# How to show square on digit in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

How to show square on any digit in flutter UI like above example?

Answer (score 6):

Just use the Unicode character `\u00b2` which is superscript 2.

```
'18.5 kg/m\u00b2 - 25 kg/m\u00b2'
```

Answer (score 2):

No native way to do this I think.But you can refer latex-related package like [`flutter_tex`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tex) to implement this. 
A screenshot from its [demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YiNbVEXV_NM):
[image: show square digit]

Answer (score 0):

you can reach the superscript letters like this with `FontFeatures`:

```
Text(
  'The isotope 238U decays to 206Pb',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Sorts Mill Goudy',
    fontFeatures: <FontFeature>[
      FontFeature.superscripts(),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

in this case, we used the `superscripts()` which will show the letters as a superscript.

read about it more in the [official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/FontFeature/FontFeature.superscripts.html)